# How to set all matching rows property isDelete to False?

Tags: nhibernate

Using Hql or criteria, how can I update many rows and set a property to false?

ie. SQL would be:

UPDATE UserOrders
SET isDeleted = 0 -- (boolean false)
WHERE uID = 234

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use the business object in any other way for this, I think I would bypass NHibernate in this situation.  That is: do not use HQL, but issue a native SQL query.  (NHibernate allows you to do this; check the CreateSQLQuery of the ISession).

Why would I do that ?
Because, when you issue such a query using HQL, I think that NH will fetch every entity out of the database, change its property, and then update its corresponding row.   Imagine the performance hit.
But, I think that HQL does not support UPDATE queries (but I could be mistaken on that one).